# Difference between "DateTime?" and "DateTime". (trying to get value from datepicker)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm quite new to **WPF** and **C#** so don't blame me for asking this maybe silly question.

I have my WPF app with two **datepickers**. I want to get the DateTime out of them when it changes and to use it as my variable for some other stuff in the app. So I have for each of them something like this(method was automatically generated by VS):

```
private void datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            date1 = datePicker1.SelectedDate;
        }
```

but the problem is that the date in the datepicker is format **DateTime?** not **DateTime** and I really don't know what does that question mark there mean and why it is there. I tried some research but didn't find anything that would help me. If u see some better way of getting the date from that datepicker u can help me with it too. I just need it in my xaml.cs code not in xaml and I'm not really into using bindings cause I'm not sure if it works how I need in this case.

Thanks for any answer.

**Edit:** I would like to add information that it shows me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to
>   'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DateTime with `?` is [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) DateTime, it can hold null values. For your case you can do :

```
private void datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(datePicker1.SelectedDate.HasValue)
         date1 = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
}
```

[`Nullable<T>` C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

> In C# and Visual Basic, you mark a value type as nullable by using the
>   ? notation after the value type. For example, int? in C# or Integer?
>   in Visual Basic declares an integer value type that can be assigned
>   null.

Comment: Weird.. I was adding there the .Value but it didn't work without the if... Well thx :)

Comment: @goodfriend, you are welcome, yes it is weird, it should show work with just `Value`, but its good to check for `HasValue`

Answer (score 0):

A nullable DateTime can be null.

The `DateTime` struct itself does not provide a null option. But the `DateTime?` nullable type allows you to assign the null literal to the `DateTime` type. It provides another level of indirection in the object model.

> Program that uses null DateTime struct: C#

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Declare a nullable DateTime instance and assign to null.
    // ... Change the DateTime and use the Test method (below).
    //
    DateTime? value = null;
    Test(value);
    value = DateTime.Now;
    Test(value);
    value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Test(value);
    //
    // You can use the GetValueOrDefault method on nulls.
    //
    value = null;
    Console.WriteLine(value.GetValueOrDefault());
    }

    static void Test(DateTime? value)
    {
    //
    // This method uses the HasValue property.
    // ... If there is no value, the number zero is written.
    //
    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(0);
    }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0
9/29/2009 9:56:21 AM
9/30/2009 9:56:21 AM
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Originally found [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `DateTime` without any value (ie, null). It will always have a default value (`DateTime.MinValue`).

A `DateTime?`, on the other hand, is a sort of wrapper around `DateTime`, which allows you to keep it *undefined*. This can be very useful, for instance if you want to let the user leave one of the date-fields blank (no date selected = `Null`).

Remember that you'll need to use `DateTime?` as the parameter type of any methods that need to do work related to this, though. If you rely on other libraries, or have to pass this data to other components, etc, then you can sometimes face awkward situations.

**Typical challenge/decision:** 
"*I'm using `DateTime?` in component **X**, which talks to component **Y**, which uses `DateTime` - should I rewrite **Y** to handle `DateTime?`, or should I translate any `DateTime?`-object with a value of `Null` into a `DateTime`-object with a value of `DateTime.MinValue` to represent unselected/invalid dates? Or perhaps I should just let it throw an exception in **Y**...?*"

Just something to be aware of and think about when working with `DateTime?`..

Answer (score 0):

A nullable DateTime can be null. The DateTime struct itself does not provide a null option. But the "DateTime?" nullable type allows you to assign the null literal to the DateTime type. It provides another level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Created Date without empty or nullable
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

//with Nullable or empty
public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
```

[Result View: Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiWvi.png)